# how to change class dynamically in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to change the class of an html entity using angularjs by following the steps shown in this [link](http://techfunda.com/Code/Demo/607) but it's not working. I have two buttons I want to show as active when clicked so I have an "active" class for this. I want to change class dynamically using angularjs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab-btn" >
    <input type="button"   ng-class="active"  ng-show="about"   ng-click="show==1" value="About" />
    <input type="button" ng-show="help"    ng-click="show = 2" value="Help"/>    
    <input type="button" ng-show="Info"    ng-click="show = 3" value="Special" />        
    <input type="button" ng-show="Service" ng-click="show = 4" value="Service" />            
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.active = '';
$scope.show = 1;
$scope.show1 = function(){

    $scope.show2 = false;
    $scope.show3 = false;
    $scope.show4 = false;

    if ($scope.active.length === 0) {
        $scope.active = 'active';
    } else {
        $scope.active = '';
    }                 
};
```

Comment: use the ng-class directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: there is a lot of questions about how to conditionally apply classes in angular. please search stackoverflow for your question before asking it

Comment: Yes ng-class is angular way to use

Comment: Also, your `ng-click` compares `show` to 1, not sets it.

Comment: @Romski-i have gone thru the sane link,but my problem is diffrent ,i have successfully changed class of a DIV NOT A BUTTON

Comment: People down vote the question because it has been asked dozens of times, when a simple search of SO or looking at the docs for `ng-class` would unveil the answer. People are more inclined to help when you show you have tried to help your self. If you said you have searched but your still confused could they explain `x, y and z` you'd get a better response.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ng-class` incorrectly: its expression comprises of an object where each property is a class and the value is an expression to evaluate to conditionally apply that class when truthy.

So `ng-class="{active: isActive: inActive: !isActive}"` would apply the `active` class if the variable `isActive` is a truthy value otherwise it would apply the class `inActive`.

For your use case it depends on the wider scope of your application and how you generate your buttons but I have followed a different approach in the past.

If you define a model for your buttons, complete with active flags, disabled flags, title, etc. you can control your buttons state much easier.

This will allow you to dynamically add buttons, change text, enable buttons etc. Even more so if you provide your nav section with its own controller and expose it through services to the rest of your application, but that may be a bit much.

Hopefully, this fiddle will help http://jsfiddle.net/p66mv6tn/1/